# Is it possible to send data from client to server in Android bluetooth via inputstream-outputstream?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Now I am able only to send data from server to client. I put it into OutputStream on server and receive from InputStream on client.

Is it any way to do it in another direction? I haven't found anything about that on android.com or any other resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void connectBTSerial(BluetoothDevice bdev){
   BluetoothSocket bSocket = bdev.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString(SOME_UUID)); 
   bSocket.connect();
   InputStream in = bSocket.getInputStream();
   OutputStream out = bSocket.getOutputStream();
}
```

Comment: Are u sure? Did u try this code on practice? Cause I implement right the same. And the outputstream comes from server and the inputstream comes to client. And one device is always client and another is server... anyway if u have links of working code I would be grateful!

Comment: Yes, I use this code to connect android application to a BT serial device(server). Client can get stream and also send streams. It doesnt matter.